# Remote Desktop 22.04 from Mac

Tags: mac, vnc

I had to tinker for a while before realizing my mac was confused by the default setting for creating vnc connections on ubuntu. Here's a summary

to enable vnc access to your ubuntu desktop

Settings -> Sharing -> Remote Desktop

then Enable Legacy VNC Protocol. Notice there is a three-vertical-dot submenu. Select "require password". The default, "New connections must ask for access", confuses my mac. It could be a timing issue.

You can then use the native vnc client on mac by going to

Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server

and then entering

```
vnc://<your server name or address>
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had the problem earlier, using the earlier ubuntu version 20.04. It seems to happen because the two systems cannot negotiate an appropriate encryption level to use between them.

You can run "gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false" in your ubuntu terminal to solve the problem.

Comment: This answer solved my problem! My problem was "not compatible".

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful to anyone, Microsoft Remote Desktop now works with Ubuntu without having to check 'Enable Legacy VNC Protocol'.

To use it:

- Turn on Remote Desktop in Ubuntu 'Sharing' settings.
- Enter a username/password in the Remote Desktop 'Authentication' section.
- Connect ('Add PC...') via the Microsoft Remote Desktop app. All default settings were fine for me.

Comment: I just tried this but I don't know if the port opened auto.